# How can I solve for r?

Tags: computational-mathematics

How can this be solved: Using the Geometric Series Sum formula: $S_n = \frac{a (r^n-1)}{r-1}$ It is impossible to get $r$ with normal algebra. But with other methods it is possible. for example to find $a$ it would look like this with normal algebra: $a = (Sn*r-Sn)/((r^n)-1)$  So how do i find $r$ ?

Comment: I don't know if the formula is helpful; it might be better to leave it in the form $S_n = a(1 + r + r^2 +\cdots+ r^{n-1})$. Then you'd have to solve a polynomial equation, with something like the quadratic formula.

Comment: Are you taking an infinite series? The equation $S_\infty = \frac{a}{1-r}$ is easy to solve for $r$ (but it's only valid if $|r| < 1$).

Comment: for example to find a it would look like this: a = (Sn*r-Sn)/((r^n)-1)

Comment: For given values of $S$, $n$ and $a$, there is no formula that gives you the value of $r$. You would have to use an iterative procedure.

Comment: how do I use a iterative procedure on this?

Comment: Remove from hold please i edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide $(1-r)$ into $(1-r^n)$ you have the polynomial $1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n-1}$. Then you are left with the equation
$ar^{n-1} + \cdots + ar + (a-S_n) = 0$. If $r$ is rational then it can be found with the rational root theorem. If not you would have to solve it using an approximation method like Newton's method.

Examples by request:

**Example 1.** Suppose someone gives you $a=2,~ S_n=\frac{259}{108},~ n=4$ and we wish to determine $r$.

Then we have the equation
$$2r^3 + 2r^2 + 2r - \frac{43}{108} = 0 \\
216r^3 + 216r^2 + 216r -43 = 0$$
If this has a rational root, it it must have a numerator as one of the divisors of the constant term, $\pm1,~ \pm 43$, and a denominator as one of the divisors of the leading coefficient, $1,~ 2,~ 3,~ 4,~ 6,~ 8,~ 9,~ 12,~ 18,~ 24,~ 27,~ 36,~ 54,~ 72,~ 108,~ 216$. Trying these in turn we find $r=\frac{1}{6}$.

**Example 2.** Suppose someone gives you $a = \sqrt{2}, S_n = 123.2,$ and $n=10$. Because of the uncertainty in the representation by computer of $a$ and possible truncation of $S_n$ we cannot be sure of an exact solution.

We have the equation

$$\sqrt{2}r^9 + \cdots + \sqrt{2}r - 121.78578 = 0$$
We make some guess, $r_0 = 5$. Then we get our new guess $r_1$ by

$$r_{n+1} = r_n + \frac{f(r_n)}{f'(r_n)},~ f'(r) = 9\sqrt{2}r^8 + 8\sqrt{2}r^7 + \cdots + \sqrt{2}$$

After 13 iterations we have an estimate $r=1.4454$ which differs from the previous estimate by less than $0.0001$. Checking this answer in our original formula we get $S_n^* = 123.1952$ which is accurate to what our user provided us with within the precision they gave us.

Comment: Thanks a lot  :)  but what would f(x) be if i use Newtons method?

Comment: The polynomial I described: $f(x) = ar^{n-1} + \cdots + ar + (a - S_n)$.

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: ok I have added two examples @Hannokruger

Comment: Thanks a lot !!